# Need to have input tag instead of browse button in uploading a file in php

Tags: php, html, css

I'm a newbie in php programming. I'm currently creating a user profile in which i need to allow users to upload a profile picture. So I've coded like this

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('','class="form-horizontal span4"');?>
<img src="PATH TO IMAGE" />
<input type="text" name="userfile" />
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Upload" />

<?php echo form_close();?>
```

and so I'm getting a structure like the one above.
[image]

But what I need is something like the one in the second image.Is this possible... If yes please help or at least share a link.

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between the images?

Comment: It looks the same to me. can you tell me the difference. haha

Comment: sorry guys my mistake..

Comment: use <input type="file"> in your form

Comment: windows.... is there any way to open the browse dialog onclicking in the input box

Comment: create an `<input type='file' class='hidden'>` which is hidden, then just use javascript in `btnclick` invoke the input type file..

Comment: if i use <input type="file"/> It appears with browse button ... actually i dont want the button or if its not possible it can be merged with input box

Comment: Why do you want users to type the path instead of being able to comfortably choose a file from a file browser like they do on every other site? Do you have an example of this working in practice somewhere?

Comment: I've edited the second image please tell me its possible to do like that.....

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you do is move the default upload input outside of the page for example by setting it's absolute left to -300px. Then you have your own button click to trigger the real one with javascript. Easy as that. P.S. you cannot hide it with visibility or display:none, because it won't trigger. Fortunately moving it away doesn't disable it.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the default value i.e: `Browse` but this can be achieved with css by overlapping an image over browse button.

[image: See Below snapshot]

In Css Somethig like that(`customize it according to your HTML attribute`):

```
div.fakefile img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 -96px;
}
```

As per your comment `I want to browse using browse button and when upload is clicked i need to upload`.In addition to this:

```
<input type="submit" value="upload" name="sub"/>
<input type="file"  name="img"/>
```

Now you can submit the form by pressing upload button and the image will be uploaded if you have coded for that.Use this [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) for uploading

Comment: Why two buttons ?? you want to upload the image by browse  button or Upload ??

Comment: I want to browse using browse button and when upload is clicked i need to upload